# vba Filling Internet Explorer Forms with Excel Data

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Situation:  I am filling fields on a website in Internet Explorer with data from Excel.  It is an existing web page that the user has already navigated to, then clicks a button to add the Excel data to the fields.  The code below does the job just fine on one page of the website, with the exception of the last line.  The last line is a drop-down selection instead of an input box.  I am not able to get this one to work.  Any guidance that can be given is greatly appreciated!

Addtl Info:  I am using IE11, I have the function and the subs, each in a separate module.

This one works.

> ```
>     'This Must go at the top of your module. It's used to set IE as the active window
>     Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As LongPtr
>
>
>
>     Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object
>
>         Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
>         Dim sURL As String
>         Dim retVal As Object
>
>         Set retVal = Nothing
>         Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>         Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
>
>
>         For Each o In objShellWindows
>             sURL = ""
>             On Error Resume Next  'because may not have a "document" property
>             'Check the URL and if it's the one you want then
>             ' assign the window object to the return value and exit the loop
>             sURL = o.document.Location
>             On Error GoTo 0
>             If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
>                 Set retVal = o
>                 Exit For
>             End If
>         Next o
>
>         Set GetIE = retVal
>
>     End Function
>
>     Option Explicit
>
>     Private Sub FillWebForm_FLBlue_AddNewEE()
>
>         Dim objIE As Object
>         Dim ie As Object
>         Dim HWNDSrc As Long
>         Dim xSheetName As String
>
>         xSheetName = "FloridaBlue"
>
>         MsgBox "Open Internet Explorer and navigate to the webpage that contains the fields to be filled, then click Okay."
>
>         'Look for a specific URL in an existing instance of Internet Explorer.
>         Set ie = GetIE("https://secure2.benefitfocus.com/hradmin/task/enrollment/sponsor/employee/CreateEmployee/")
>
>         'make browser visible (if existing instance of IE)
>         ie.Visible = True
>
>         'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
>         HWNDSrc = ie.hwnd
>
>         'Set IE as Active Window
>         SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
>
>         'Add a new employee
>         ie.document.all("SSN").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("d32")
>         ie.document.all("firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("e32")
>         ie.document.all("lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("g32")
>         ie.document.all("suffix").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("h32")
>         ie.document.all("birthDate").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("i32").Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")
>         ie.document.all("gender").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("j32")
>         ie.document.all("address1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("k32")
>         ie.document.all("address2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("l32")
>         ie.document.all("city").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("m32")
>         ie.document.all("state").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("n32")
>         ie.document.all("zip").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("o32")
>         ie.document.all("country").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("p32")
>         ie.document.all("hireDate").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("q32").Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")
>         IE.document.all("categorySelections").Focus
>         IE.document.all("categorySelections").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("r32")
> ```

This is the code that doesn't work.  On this one, I get an error on ie.visible.  I've tried different variations of this but the closest I got was filling the fields, but site didn't recognize that data was entered into the fields; it said they still needed to be populated. I did notice that the URL below has "control" in it.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

> ```
>     Private Sub FillWebForm_FLBlue_AddNewDep()
>
>     Dim ie As Object
>     Dim HWNDSrc As Long
>     Dim xSheetName As String
>
>     xSheetName = "FloridaBlue"
>
>     'Look for a specific URL in an existing instance of Internet Explorer.
>     Set ie = GetIE("https://secure2.benefitfocus.com/hradmin/control/dependentBeneficiaryListAction#dependent/new")
>
>     'make browser visible (if existing instance of IE)
>     ie.Visible = True 'The error occurs here.  Object not found.
>
>     'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
>     HWNDSrc = ie.hwnd
>
>     'Set IE as Active Window
>     SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
>
>     ie.document.all("rawSsn").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("d44")
>     ie.document.all("firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("e44")
>     ie.document.all("lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("g44")
>     ie.document.all("suffix").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("h44")
>     ie.document.all("dob-alt").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("i44").Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")
>     ie.document.all("gender").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("j44")
>     ie.document.all("relationship").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xSheetName).Range("q44").Value
> ```

Comment: Which line is setting the value for dropdown?

Comment: I am not sure about the field you are talking about, but you need to add a line IE.document.all("categorySelections").FireEvent ("onchange") once the value is set.

Comment: Youdescribe at least two problems in the above. Which is the actual problem?

Comment: I will try adding the FireEvent("onchange") to the first code.  On the second code, the problem is that I am getting an error on the line for ie.visible, but it's the same code as the one above it that does not produce an error.

Comment: @J.B. I added IE.document.all("categorySelections").FireEvent ("onchange")  and got Run Time Error Script Out of Range.  I tried this before and after adding the value/  I also tried .innertext = and .value=, and got the same error on both.

Answer (score 0):

With J.B.'s suggestion, I got this working with .focus, .value =, .FireEvent ("onchange")

Thanks!

Comment: From your last post, It looks like your 1 issue is solved. If we talk about 2nd issue than can you please inform us, which error you got while making the IE visible may help us to understand the issue. Thanks for your understanding.